# Don't Work gspreads when i try to edit google sheet

Tags: python, json, gspread

I'am have a problem with gspreads, i registered API for google sheets and include json to my code, i already open access to the file for robot email, but i also see one error: raise SpreadsheetNotFound
gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound. What to do?

my code:

```
import gspread

sa = gspread.service_account("creds.json")
sh = sa.open("filename")

wks = sh.worksheet("Sheet1")

print(wks.row_count)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 121, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files(title, folder_id),
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gspread\utils.py", line 88, in finditem
    return next(item for item in seq if func(item))
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\Downloads\google-sheets-video-1-sacc-reading\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    sh = sa.open("url")
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 129, in open
    raise SpreadsheetNotFound
gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound
```

Edit:
I fixed this error, but now there is another one
New code:

```
import gspread

sa = gspread.service_account("creds.json")
sh = sa.open("filename", "D")

wks = sh.worksheet("Sheet1")

print(wks.row_count)
```

New error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\Downloads\google-sheets-video-1-sacc-reading\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    sh = sa.open('url', 'D')
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 121, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files(title, folder_id),
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 96, in list_spreadsheet_files
    res = self.request("get", url, params=params).json()
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 71, in request
    raise APIError(response)
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'errors': [{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'message': 'File not found: .', 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'fileId'}], 'code': 404, 'message': 'File not found: .'}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the full traceback.  Though on preliminary glance, do you have a spreadsheet with the filename "filename"?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 121, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files(title, folder_id),
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gspread\utils.py", line 88, in finditem
    return next(item for item in seq if func(item))
StopIteration

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\Downloads\google-sheets-video-1-sacc-reading\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    sh = sa.open("url")
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 129, in open
    raise SpreadsheetNotFound
gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound

Comment: No, please include the traceback in the post and not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

From your script and `SpreadsheetNotFound gspread.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound.`, I thought that in this case, the reason for your issue might be due to that the owner of the Spreadsheet of `filename` is not the service account or the Spreadsheet is not shared with the service account.

If your Spreadsheet of `filename` is in your Google Drive and the owner of it is you, how about the following methods?

1. Share the Spreadsheet with the email of the service account.
2. [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)

   - In this case, your account is required to be a Google Workspace account.